# Unable to load class 'org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilder'

Tags: android, gradle, rx-java

I try to read the source code of the project RxJava and I think the older version perhaps easier to learn.
so I download the version RxJava-0.1.2 and RxJava-1.0.0.
but when I try to run them in Android Studio,I got a lot of errors.
such as :
`Unable to load class 'org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilder'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:`

- `Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)`
- `The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)`
- `Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.`

`In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.`

I try to change the `distributionUrl` and I got `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration`

then I change all `plusConfigurations += configurations.provided` to `plusConfigurations += [configurations.provided]` and it still doesn't work.
How can I resolve these errors?
or How can I learn the project?

Comment: The officially supported RxJava version 2 has been completely rewritten from scratch. RxJava 1 has been discontinued so it is very likely you'll learn outdated internal concepts and structures not transferable to the latest version. Also those use ancient Gradle version so they are likely no longer supported by IDEs.

Comment: @akarnokd   Thanks for your reply! So the best reading method is that clone RxJava v2.0.0 and delete the earlier versions? I will try it later.

Comment: Please start from the latest version, 2.1.14 releasing tomorrow, so you at least avoid the bugs and mistakes fixed in the past 1.5 years.

Comment: @akarnokd ok! I have cloned the latest version now.I also find the issue#4186 of RxJava in github.Is this issue outdated?

Comment: We don't use that automatic version increment plugin anymore but I have not tried the zip option.

Comment: @akarnokd sorry! I have not expressed clearly. I found some books that were recommended in the issue. And I wanna to ask "Are these books outdated?". I cloned the latest version by git and it works well :)